# Clean Project входит в Rebuild Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Или нет?

Т.е. делаем Rebuild, Clean выполнится тоже?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, rebuild project не только удаляет все артефакты, но и перестраивает проект.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170318/there-is-no-difference-in-android-studio-2-3-3-between-clean-and-rebuild-so-why/47179692#47179692) можно посмотреть подробные логи clean и rebuild